# How to check if a list is one step away from being perfect according to a particular requirement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose there is a list called `my_list` that can have up to 4 different unique values e.g. `my_list = ['d','a','d','c','d','c','b','a','b']`. We call `my_list` a perfect list if, among the list's unique elements, there are at least 3 occurrences of any element, at least 2 occurrences of another element and at least 1 occurrence of another element. For example, `my_list = ['d','a','d','c','d','c','b','a','b']` is perfect according to the criteria since the number of occurences are as follows:

```
'd' = 3 (at least 3 times)
'a' = 2 (at least 2)
'c' = 2 (at least 1)
'b' = 2 (at least 2)
```

therefore the requirement of at least 3, 2 and 1 repetitions is met whereas `another_list = ['d','a','d','c','d','b']` is not perfect as:

```
'd' = 3 
'a' = 1 
'c' = 1 
'b' = 1
```

so the requirement of 3, 2, 1 is not there. Please note that the order is irrelevant. In `another_list`, if we only add one 'a' or one 'c' or one 'b', then it will become perfect; in other words, it is only one step away from being perfect. I am looking for a function that takes a list and returns `True` if the list is only one step away from becoming perfect; otherwise, it returns `False`. I have coded as follows:

```
def fun(some_list):

    unique = list(set(some_list))

        dict = {}
        for i in unique:
            dict[i] = unique.count(i)

        counts = list(dict.values())
```

which finds the counts of unique elements in the list but I need help to complete the function to check if the list is one step away from being perfect based on the above explanation.

Comment: Start with `collections.Counter`.

Comment: "which finds the counts of unique elements in the list but I need help to complete the function to check if the list is one step away from being perfect based on the above explanation." Well, what do you imagine is the next logical step in the process? What happens when you try to write code to do that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
def almost_perfect(d):
  r = collections.Counter(d)
  c = {b:a for a, b in r.items()}
  k = [i for i in range(1, 4) if i not in c]
  return len(k) == 1 and (k[0]+1 in c or any(i+1 == k[0] and sum(j == i for j in r.values()) > 1 for i in c))

vals = ['d','a','d','c','d','b']
vals1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
vals2 = ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c'] 
print(almost_perfect(vals))
print(almost_perfect(vals1))
print(almost_perfect(vals2))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: few things, you should mention this only works with Python3.8+ because of the walrus operator and what's with jamming all that code in one line, makes it less readable?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: The function needs some modification if `vals = ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c']` the function returns True but it should return False.

Comment: Still doesn't work, consider `vals = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']`, the modified function returns False but according to the criteria in OP's question it should return True.

Comment: @Coder Please see the OP's post, the goal is to see if an inherently *imperfect* list can be made perfect in a single step. The function should return `True` if the input can be made perfect in a single step.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Lets look at `vals = ['a' , 'a',  'b',  'b',  'c',  'c']` again, in only one step that is either adding 'a' or 'b' or 'c', `vals` will become perfect. The pattern in `vals = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']` is 2, 2, 2 and if we add just one of those mentioned elements then the pattern will be 3, 2, 2 (in any order). Please consider the term "at least" in the OP's question.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Hence, your proposed function should return True with `vals = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']` while it currently returns False.